# jQuery, selecting form elements by name, getting: Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@name="reset"]

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select an select element by name I found this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/225db2835234d8a2/a45abe5ee8e90bcb?lnk=gst&q=select+form+elements+by+name#a45abe5ee8e90bcb) showing how to do it, and I followed it but I'm getting Syntax error. I'm using jquery 1.4.1, here's my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(  $('select[@name="country[0]"]').val() );
        })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <select name="country[0]">
        <option value="23">test</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `$('select[name="country[0]"]')` instead.

Using XPath in your selectors, which includes prefixing attribute names with `@` has been removed from jQuery.

For more information, see the documentation of the [attributeEquals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring this out by removing the @ symbol:

```
$('select[name="country[0]"]').val()
```

What does/did the @ symbol do?

Comment: the @ symbol is valid xpath for attributes. it's deprecated in 1.3+esque jquery.